# if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 AWS SSM

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-config

I am trying to use AWS SSM in my project by the following way:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
  
const ssmClient = new AWS.SSM({
    apiVersion: 'latest',
    region: 'REGION'
  });

  export const localEnvironment = () => {
    ssmClient.getParameter({
        Name: `SSM-PATH`,
        WithDecryption: true,
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (data?.Parameter) {
            return data.Parameter
        }
});}
```

In my ~/.aws/credentials, I have added the following:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

and can query the parameters using the AWS CLI. However, when I run it in my Reach APP, I get the following error:

> "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set
> AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"

Things that I have tried:

1. I exported the access key ID and secret access key in my terminal as well as WS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 and no difference was obtained.
2. I hardcoded the values in the code by the following way:

const SESConfig = {
apiVersion: "VERSION",
accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
accessSecretKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
region: "REGION"
}
AWS.config.update(SESConfig);

The above worked as expected and I was able to retrieve the parameters. However, I want to keep it through the AWS credentials and I am not sure what I can do different to make it work. In addition, is it best practice to use a local environment variable files for storing these credentials?